# Memory Profile Java JNI classes/structs that are generated in C/C++

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface

We are using Java 11 with Spring Boot and we are running our application in Docker Container in AWS ECS.
Our application is responsible for processing images, and our Java code calls C/C++ code through JNI in order for some image manipulation.
Recently, after some changes have been introduced on C side, we are seeing Container out of memory issues (not JVM OOM).
My question being the following -> is there some tool like VisualVM where you can see what objects are there for the native memory (not the Java Heap - VisualVM does that)
This would mean something like profiling with `jcmd ${process} VM.native_memory`, but instead of getting only the below output from that operation, to get something more in detail where you can see which C/C++ classes/structs are in memory at that time?
[image]

Best Regards

Comment: Usually no. Human readable names are useless to a computer, so they are among the first things to go. A debug build with the right tools may be able to provide more information. Ig f you add which toolchain are you using to build the C and C++ code to the question we may be able to offer less general information.

Comment: *Our application is responsible for processing images* -- Is this a 32-bit application or 64-bit application?  If it's 32-bit, and images can be held in memory, large images or images with high bit-depth levels can easily exhaust the memory.

Comment: Replace your native memory allocator with jemalloc; that allows you to at least trace allocations to the allocation callstack.

Comment: Run your whole application (Java code) through `https://valgrind.org` or `gprof` - you can take a look at a sample here: https://youtu.be/0CAuWuMkKBM (However, it is focused on macOS based profiling)